# Calculus fundamental theorem proof rolles i i

Tags: calculus

Hi I have recently learned rolles theorem and I don't quite understand why the number c that we choose has to be in the open interval (a,b) why can it not be on the closed interval.for example a constant function such as y=2 has a f'(c)=0 when c =a or b which is in the closed interval.the same thing confuses me for the mean value theorem.some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What you wrote for a constant function is correct, but it has also $f'(c)=0$ for a $c \in (a,b)$.

Comment: Does the same apply to the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolle's theorem states that if $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous, if $f(a)=f(b)$, and if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, then there is some $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. So, we are not even assuming that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ or at $b$. And if we were, then yes, $f'$ *might* have a zero at $a$ or at $b$ (or both). But asserting that it has a zero on $(a,b)$ is a stronger statement than claiming that it has a zero on $[a,b]$. So, why would we claim a weaker statement when we can easily prove a stronger one?